# Can 'shall' - not should - be succeeded after injunctive verbs?

Tags: modal-verbs

> “You had this morning a breakfast which you could not eat; you must be
>   hungry. I have **ordered** that a lunch of bread and cheese **shall** be
>   served to all.” (Jane Eyre)

I’ve known that if subject clause has the words like *order*, its object clause needs to have *should plus verb* or *root verb*. How can I understand the coming of ‘shall’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Shall* is quite rare in contemporary English, other than in questions that make an offer or a suggestion. Charlotte Brontë’s use is, of course, perfectly grammatical, but she uses *shall* where a modern author might use *will*. More often, however, you would probably find a different construction altogether. Possible alternatives (with the first less likely in American English) are:

> I have ordered that a lunch of bread and cheese is served to all.
>
> I have ordered that a lunch of bread and cheese be served to all.
>
> I have ordered a lunch of bread and cheese to be served to all.
>
> I have ordered that a lunch of bread and cheese should be served to
>   all.

Comment: +1 I think, too, that *should* would imply (more strongly for Brontë perhaps than today) some doubt as to whether the order would be carried out. *I have ordered that lunch will be served at noon rather than 1:00* would be unremarkable today.

Comment: @StoneyB. Somewhat paradoxically, it also seems to suggest a degree of compulsion.

Comment: Yes - particularly if *will* is stressed. A generation ago you often heard US newscasters read things like *The President stated that the US will provide immediate relief* with an odd stress on *will*; my father claimed this came of almost universal service in the military, where any announcements on the post PA were read as commands: *There **will** be a showing of Road to Monaco at nineteen hundred hours.*